# find virtualenv current package directory for vim

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, ctags

I want to be able to reach source code from my virtualenv library via ctags but to be able to do this I need to know which virtualenv is currently active, so for example, I have this code in my .vimrc which appends django to my ctags index:

```
nnoremap <F7> :!ctags -R --python-kinds=-i -a ~/.virtualenvs/MYPROJECT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/*<CR>
```

Instead of hardcoding the path I want it to do something like:

```
nnoremap <F7> :!ctags -R --python-kinds=-i -a CURRENT_PROJECT_PACKAGES_PATH/django/*
```

so I can index packages from the current project I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $VIRTUAL_ENV to get to your library, so it'd be something like this

```
nnoremap <F7> :!ctags -R --python-kinds=-i -a $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/*
```

Comment: It's funny how simple it was and how I never thought about doing it that way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable like `let g:current_proj = "~/.virtualenvs/MYPROJECT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"` then read it in with an exe:

```
nnoremap <F7> :exe "!ctags -R --python-kinds=-i -a " . g:current_proj . "django/*"<cr>
```

or you can just directly use an environment variable:

```
nnoremap <F7> :exe "!ctags -R --python-kinds=-i -a " . $CURRENT_PROJECT_PACKAGES . "django/*"<cr>
```

Comment: What I would like to do is not to hardcode the path to my site-packages folder since it varies depending on which project I am working on my virtualenv. Maybe I should clarify that the `$CURRENT_PROJECT_PACKAGES` variable doesn't really exists heh

Comment: You can update variables or environment variables in real time for these solutions. For example, you could do `:let g:current_proj = "/path/to/different/virtualenv"` inside vim, or you could `:!export $CURRENT_PROJECT_PACKAGES = "/path/to/virtualenv"`. You might have to write a script to change the environment variable when you change virtualenvs.

Comment: If you don't want to create the `$CURRENT_PROJECT_PACKAGES` environment variable, then maybe you want to look at a plugin like [command-t](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T) or [FuzzyFinder](https://github.com/vim-scripts/FuzzyFinder).

Comment: it's a solution but it's a hassle to do that, It would be easier for me to create a `F8` with my other project path in that case. I know there is a command `cdsitepackages` which returns the path to the current active sitepackage folder it but it doesn't work inside the .vimrc for some reason

Comment: Try ```:!export $CURRENT_PROJECT_PACKAGES = `cdsitepackages` ``` then ```:echo $CURRENT_PROJECT_PACKAGES```